# Redirect to a another page in my site, if viewed from tablets and smartphones

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, tablet, smartphone

I hope you can help me out with a problem I have. I have created a large visual site, and I don't want to make users see it from phones or tablets, since the loadtime can be 6 seconds+ on 3g net. I don't have the time to create the site for all formats, only desktop.

I'm using apache server and the bootstrap htaccess file(edited a bit). Is it possible to make redirects to lets say www.mypage.org to www.mypage.org/mobile_message.html using the htaccess file? I want the costumer to get a massage on smartphones and tablets to say "Hey there, our site is not able for this device, please check our site on a desktop".

ANy solutions ? :):)

Mikkel Madsen

htaccess file:

```
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # | CORS-enabled images                                                        |
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Send the CORS header for images when browsers request it.
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CORS_Enabled_Image
    # http://blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html
    # http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/using-cors-to-load-webgl-textures-from-cross-domain-      images/

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
   </IfModule>

   # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   # | Web fonts access                                                           |
   # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   # Allow access from all domains for web fonts

   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
   </IfModule>


   # ##############################################################################
   # # ERRORS                                                                     #
   # ##############################################################################

   # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   # | 404 error prevention for non-existing redirected folders                   |
   # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   # Prevent Apache from returning a 404 error for a rewrite if a directory
   # with the same name does not exist.
   # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#multiviews
   # http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3808792.htm

   Options -MultiViews

   # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   # | Custom error messages / pages                                              |
   # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   # You can customize what Apache returns to the client in case of an error (see
   # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument), e.g.:

   ErrorDocument 404 /404.html


   # ##############################################################################
   # # INTERNET EXPLORER                                                          #
   # ##############################################################################

   # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   # | Better website experience                                                  |
   # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   # Force IE to render pages in the highest available mode in the various
   # cases when it may not: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/ie-mode.pdf.

   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
    # `mod_headers` can't match based on the content-type, however, we only
    # want to send this header for HTML pages and not for the other resources
    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?  g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svgz?|  ttf|vcf|webapp|webm|webp|woff|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>
   </IfModule>

   # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   # | Cookie setting from iframes                                                |
   # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   # Allow cookies to be set from iframes in IE.

   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set P3P "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi   IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\""
   </IfModule>

enter code here# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Screen flicker                                                             |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers (this only works in
# combination with the `ExpiresByType` directives for images from below).

BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary


# ##############################################################################
# # MIME TYPES AND ENCODING                                                    #
# ##############################################################################

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Proper MIME types for all files                                            |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_mime.c>

  # Audio
    AddType audio/mp4                                   m4a f4a f4b
    AddType audio/ogg                                   oga ogg

  # JavaScript
    # Normalize to standard type (it's sniffed in IE anyways):
    # http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
    AddType application/javascript                      js
    AddType application/json                            json

  # Video
    AddType video/mp4                                   mp4 m4v f4v f4p
    AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
    AddType video/webm                                  webm
    AddType video/x-flv                                 flv

  # Web fonts
    AddType application/font-woff                       woff
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot

    # Browsers usually ignore the font MIME types and sniff the content,
    # however, Chrome shows a warning if other MIME types are used for the
    # following fonts.
    AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
    AddType font/opentype                               otf

    # Make SVGZ fonts work on iPad:
    # https://twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
    AddType     image/svg+xml                           svg svgz
    AddEncoding gzip                                    svgz

  # Other
    AddType application/octet-stream                    safariextz
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension              crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension               oex
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash               swf
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json         webapp
    AddType application/x-xpinstall                     xpi
    AddType application/xml                             atom rdf rss xml
    AddType image/webp                                  webp
    AddType image/x-icon                                ico
    AddType text/cache-manifest                         appcache manifest
    AddType text/vtt                                    vtt
    AddType text/x-component                            htc
    AddType text/x-vcard                                vcf

</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | UTF-8 encoding                                                             |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served as `text/html` or `text/plain`.
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# Force UTF-8 for certain file formats.
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .webapp .xml .php
</IfModule>


# ##############################################################################
# # URL REWRITES                                                               #
# ##############################################################################

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Rewrite engine                                                             |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine and enabling the `FollowSymLinks` option is
# necessary for the following directives to work.

# If your web host doesn't allow the `FollowSymlinks` option, you may need to
# comment it out and use `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` but, be aware of the
# performance impact: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/perf-tuning.html#symlinks

# Also, some cloud hosting services require `RewriteBase` to be set:
# http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/frequently-asked-question/why-is-mod-rewrite-not-working-on-my-site



# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Suppressing / Forcing the "www." at the beginning of URLs                  |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# The same content should never be available under two different URLs especially
# not with and without "www." at the beginning. This can cause SEO problems
# (duplicate content), therefore, you should choose one of the alternatives and
# redirect the other one.

# By default option 1 (no "www.") is activated:
# http://no-www.org/faq.php?q=class_b

# If you'd prefer to use option 2, just comment out all the lines from option 1
# and uncomment the ones from option 2.

# IMPORTANT: NEVER USE BOTH RULES AT THE SAME TIME!

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# Option 1: rewrite www.example.com → example.com

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# </IfModule>

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# Option 2: rewrite example.com → www.example.com

# Be aware that the following might not be a good idea if you use "real"
# subdomains for certain parts of your website.

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
#    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost [NC]
#    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=127.0.0.1
#    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# </IfModule>


# ##############################################################################
# # SECURITY                                                                   #
# ##############################################################################

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Content Security Policy (CSP)                                              |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# You can mitigate the risk of cross-site scripting and other content-injection
# attacks by setting a Content Security Policy which whitelists trusted sources
# of content for your site.

# The example header below allows ONLY scripts that are loaded from the current
# site's origin (no inline scripts, no CDN, etc). This almost certainly won't
# work as-is for your site!

# To get all the details you'll need to craft a reasonable policy for your site,
# read: http://html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy (or
# see the specification: http://w3.org/TR/CSP).

# <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
#    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svgz?|ttf|vcf|webapp|webm|webp|woff|xml|xpi)$">
#        Header unset Content-Security-Policy
#    </FilesMatch>
# </IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | File access                                                                |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Block access to directories without a default document.
# Usually you should leave this uncommented because you shouldn't allow anyone
# to surf through every directory on your server (which may includes rather
# private places like the CMS's directories).

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# Block access to hidden files and directories.
# This includes directories used by version control systems such as Git and SVN.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# Block access to backup and source files.
# These files may be left by some text editors and can pose a great security
# danger when anyone has access to them.

<FilesMatch "(^#.*#|\.(bak|config|dist|fla|inc|ini|log|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)                                                 |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Rewrite secure requests properly to prevent SSL certificate warnings, e.g.:
# prevent `https://www.example.com` when your certificate only allows
# `https://secure.example.com`.

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
#    RewriteRule ^ https://example-domain-please-change-me.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# </IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)                                      |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force client-side SSL redirection.

# If a user types "example.com" in his browser, the above rule will redirect
# him to the secure version of the site. That still leaves a window of oppor-
# tunity (the initial HTTP connection) for an attacker to downgrade or redirect
# the request. The following header ensures that browser will ONLY connect to
# your server via HTTPS, regardless of what the users type in the address bar.
# http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-websec-strict-transport-sec-14#section-6.1
# http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/transport-layer-security/

# (!) Remove the `includeSubDomains` optional directive if the subdomains are
# not using HTTPS.

# <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains"
# </IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Server software information                                                |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Avoid displaying the exact Apache version number, the description of the
# generic OS-type and the information about Apache's compiled-in modules.

# ADD THIS DIRECTIVE IN THE `httpd.conf` AS IT WILL NOT WORK IN THE `.htaccess`!

# ServerTokens Prod


# ##############################################################################
# # WEB PERFORMANCE                                                            #
# ##############################################################################

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Compression                                                                |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    # Force compression for mangled headers.
    # http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
    # (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`
    #  and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines
    #  as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives).
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                      application/javascript \
                                      application/json \
                                      application/rss+xml \
                                      application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                      application/x-font-ttf \
                      application/x-font/otf \
                      application/x-font/eot \
                      application/x-font/svg \
                      application/x-font/woff \
                                      application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                                      application/xhtml+xml \
                      application/x-javascript \
                      application/x-httpd-php \
                      application/x-httpd-fastphp \
                                      application/xml \
                                      font/opentype \
                                      image/svg+xml \
                                      image/x-icon \
                                      text/css \
                                      text/html \
                                      text/plain \
                                      text/x-component \
                                      text/xml

    </IfModule>

</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Content transformations                                                    |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Prevent some of the mobile network providers from modifying the content of
# your site: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.5.

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"
</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | ETag removal                                                               |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Since we're sending far-future expires headers (see below), ETags can
# be removed: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags.

# `FileETag None` is not enough for every server.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

FileETag None

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Expires headers (for better cache control)                                 |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# The following expires headers are set pretty far in the future. If you don't
# control versioning with filename-based cache busting, consider lowering the
# cache time for resources like CSS and JS to something like 1 week.

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

  # Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

  # HTML components (HTCs)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

  # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

  # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"

  # Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Media
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

  # Web feeds
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

  # Web fonts
    ExpiresByType application/x-font/woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"

</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Filename-based cache busting                                               |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# If you're not using a build process to manage your filename version revving,
# you might want to consider enabling the following directives to route all
# requests such as `/css/style.12345.css` to `/css/style.css`.

# To understand why this is important and a better idea than `*.css?v231`, read:
# http://stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
# </IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | File concatenation                                                         |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Allow concatenation from within specific CSS and JS files, e.g.:
# Inside of `script.combined.js` you could have
#   <!--#include file="libs/jquery.js" -->
#   <!--#include file="plugins/jquery.idletimer.js" -->
# and they would be included into this single file.

# <IfModule mod_include.c>
#    <FilesMatch "\.combined\.js$">
#        Options +Includes
#        AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES application/javascript application/json
#        SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
#    </FilesMatch>
#    <FilesMatch "\.combined\.css$">
#        Options +Includes
#        AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES text/css
#        SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
#    </FilesMatch>
# </IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Persistent connections                                                     |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Allow multiple requests to be sent over the same TCP connection:
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#keepalive.

# Enable if you serve a lot of static content but, be aware of the
# possible disadvantages!

# <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    Header set Connection Keep-Alive
# </IfModule>

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary


#rewrite on for mobile and tablets
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# detect mobile agents
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]
RewriteRule !^mobil\.html /mobil.html [L,R=302,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure it can be done in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# detect mobile agents
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mobil\.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]
RewriteRule !mobil\.html /mobil.html [L,R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry that was typo, I fixed it.

Comment: It tries to redirect, but i get a message on phone like this "This web page has a redirect loop". What is that? I used the file in this section:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Comment: Hihi :D Atleast your helping mate. Cheers !

Comment: Still getting same respond :O
The code u posted should be placed in this right?
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
</IfModule>

Comment: Yes that is fine, try from a different browser in your mobile OR claer browser cache.

Comment: Still getting that redirect loop. Anything I should look for (common mistakes that might overrule the rewrite) ?

Comment: Do I need to add something on the mobil.html file? To make it show for the devices? It redirects the url, but no content is shown.

Comment: Oh yes I thought you already have content in `/mobile_message.html`. Put some content in that file to show up on mobile phone.

Comment: I have the message that is all:) But I was thinking of some header accept something.

Comment: Just plain HTML in `/mobile_message.html` would be fine since mobile browsers are capable of displaying HTML.

Comment: That is really weird... standard html files this a paragraf with the text in it... Still has a redirect loop.

Comment: Can you dump your complete .htaccess file in your question so that I can investigate and suggest.

Comment: I have linked the htaccess file m8

Comment: Move `# detect mobile agents` rule block to the TOP of this .htaccess file.

Comment: Do you have any other .htaccess anywhere in your system?

Comment: Noep:/ It takes me to the www.mysite.dk/mobil.html, but says that redirect loop.

Comment: What I meant is that I edited my answer. Can you try it from a different mobile browser? (OR else use Firefox with some mobile agent add-on)